# How many common points do two regular polygons in a circle have?

Tags: combinatorics, polygons, plane-geometry

I was attempting to solve the following question:

> In a circle you have a $27$ sided regular polygon and a $297$ sided polygon $($all vertices are on the circle$).$ How many common points do they share?

I thought that $n\choose r$ would be helpful but I don't have any idea about how to use it.

Comment: It is 22, obviously.

Comment: How @HyJu ?????

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. Clear.

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake. It is 54=2*27, not 22=2*11.

Comment: would you please explain it to me

Comment: Each edges of $P_{27}$ could have at most two intersection with $P_{297}$. It is better to not have intersection at vertices. Such a situation can always happen when $m \geq 2n$. Here we have $m=297 \geq 54=2n$.
So the maximum number of intersection points is $54(=2n)$.

We need to tackle the general case $n<m<2n$, but I think it is always $2n$ whenever $m \geq n$.

Comment: @HyJu You haven't shown that this maximum is attained.  I also find your response to THE LONE WOLF to be very rude.  You claimed that your incorrect answer was "obvious" and "clear," without providing any justification.

Comment: @SpamIAm Should I upload my drawings? Try first.

Comment: They have either $27$ or $54$ points in common, depending on how they are positioned; note that $297=11\times27$. Try drawing a picture for a regular $5$-gon and a regular $10$-gon, and perhaps some other small examples, and see what happens.

Comment: Please ask only one question per question; I have reverted your question to include only the original question. I have also undone the edit that was grammatically incorrect and didn't add anything. If you'd like to ask about the more general case, please do so in another question. But I'd advise you to first wrestle with the problem a bit; there is a lot to learn from drawing some small examples.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** Both polygons consist of straight line segments (the edges), and both are convex. Hence each edge of the one polygon intersects at most two edges of the other polygon. (Prove this!)

Comment: So we always have the number $=2n$ where $m \geq n$ are the number of vertices of the two polygons.

Comment: @servaes, what is the role of circle ???

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. The polygons inscribed in a circle must be convex.

Comment: The role of the circle is to make both polygons intersect eachother (a lot). Otherwise you could shrink one to fit inside the other entirely, or translate one to get as few intersections as you like. And indeed they force the polygons to be convex, though this also follows from regularity, otherwise this becomes a mess.

Comment: @HyJu, As far as I think, the purpose of the website is to create a friendly environment and learn math,. But you have vandalised both the purposes. I know that under the know circumstances,, my answer can be considered wrong (That is why I have temporarily deleted it) but I still believe that there is huge possibility that OP was asking for vertices.

Comment: Mind your language and keep it in mind in future that I have been not saying so much to guys like you doesn't mean that I m dumb. We have got a long future on the site. God bless us all.

Comment: @Servaes, I posted this on your answer as I wanted you to read it too. You have been nice and under these circumstances your answer is good. +1

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. Actually this question was, before the editing, asking a definite answer as 22 or 54 above. If you felt ashamed, I'm sorry for that but you should recognize everything happened since you didn't acknowledged my opinion and thought mine is wrong(as it really is, since 22 in incorrect answer, as I corrected later.)

Comment: @HyJu, I never said that you were wrong. I was just asking for your argument that why you think you are true.

Answer (score 1):

I observed that a line of 27-gon  have 11 sides of 297-gon in minor segment if we consider 1point of both polygons coincide.

Also when 1point coincide than each point of 27-gon coincide by simmatry

So only 27 points are common

If I consider no point coincide then 1line of 27-gon intersect with 2 sides of 297- gon  so there are 54 points common.